# Blender 2.8.2 crashes on start up, requires graphics card or drivers that support OpenGL 3.3 or higher

Tags: modeling

I am trying to get Blender 2.8.2 to open on my computer but I keep getting the following error:
[image]

I have checked to see if my graphics card supports OpenGL and indeed it does, supports an OpenGL version 4.5. I have also checked to see if my system meets the minimum requirements for Blender , and they do. The specs are as follows:

- Intel Core i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
- Windows Home 64bit
- 8GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 630
- Radeon RX 560
- 1TB HDD
- 450W PSU
- 1 Monitor Display

Steps I have taken to fix this:

- Updated the graphics drivers
- Changed compatibility settings in program properties menu
- Switched the program to run on Intel HD Graphics 630 in Graphics settings
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled Drivers

Previously working versions:

- Blender 2.8.2 (When run on Intel Graphics)
- Blender 2.7.9